# What must I add to make this accordion UI module work in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

I am a beginning student of Meteor and web development. I want to make a flashcard-like app that displays, say, a proverb along with the definition of that proverb tucked into the accordion subsection. [I found an example I liked in Semantic.](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#fluid) But I don't know what to needs to be added [**to my test app**](http://meteorpad.com/pad/yySGGKDZKGu9bDAgt/Accordion%20Test) to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added https://atmospherejs.com/semantic to your project? If you have you should be able to style it exactly as they have the css on your example you've shared and the javascript should be available to you.

You also will need to add the javascript events to your meteor events file. Read more about events here https://www.meteor.com/try/4.

Comment: Think I got it, thanks. I ended up using a Template.x.rendered function (updated the above MeteorPad example). Not sure how it differs from meteor events.